# Bash "IF STATMENT with Decimal condition check"

Tags: bash, if-statement

how to use decimal condition check with IF STATEMENT. below program gives an error
while checking the if condition.

---

```
#!/bin/sh
usep=$(uptime | awk '{ print $10 }')
usep1=$(echo $usep | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)`enter code here`
usep1=${usep1%/}
usep2=${usep1%,}    #   Remove ","
echo $usep2
    if [ $usep2 <= 0.1 ]; then
    echo $usep2
    fi
```

Comment: Use `-le` for comparing numbers not `<=`

Comment: Sorry, ignore that if floats.

Answer (score 1):

For floating point arithmetic you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v s="$usep2" 'BEGIN{if (s < 0.1) print s}'
```